# Argument out of range Listbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am getting the following error on timer

```
InvalidArgument=Value '1' is not a valid value for 'index'.
```

Lines

```
string lista = listBox1.Items[bz].ToString();
bz++;
string[] split = lista.Split(';');
numero.Text = split[0];
```

how solve this?

Comment: have you added anything to listbox items? how value of `bz`is produced. this is because forexample you have 10 items in your listbox.Items but `bz` is `>=10` witch is out of range.

Comment: Yes, just added ONE item, I want to remove this error because the user can only add ONE item to the listbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#, All Collection(Array, List, ...) range is 0 to Count - 1. For example, you have an array that contains 1,000 items. In this situation array's range is 0 to 999.

And you have to check validation when accessing the collection elements like this. (This is not an optional, this is highly recommended)

```
if ( bz < 0 || bz >= listBox1.Items.Count ) {
    /* Index is out of bound */
} else {
    /* You can safely access to elements */
}
```

BTW, your problem is it:

1. You don't have enough item in the ListBox. (How about add items into ListBox ?)
2. You didn't check the validation of **bz**. (index variable)